# Convert Sql to Dql

Tags: sql, symfony, dql, doctrine-query

I need to convert this sql line to Dql.

```
SELECT * FROM agent JOIN maison ON agent.id = maison.id_agent WHERE maison.id = 2
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have a specific question? Have you read any DQL documentation? What part of the conversion process are you stuck on?

Comment: I don't know how to use Join in Doctrine, I need to select the information from the two tables (entities) simultaneously.

Comment: Please add your doctrine entities. It's hard to answer a question with only half the information. This is a very simple DQL join and it's documented very well here: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html - suggest you read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();

    return $qb->select('a')
            ->from('Your Bundle Agent', 'a')$criteria['company']))
            ->join('a. maison', 'm', 'WITH', 'a.id=m.id_maison')
            ->where('maison.id = 2')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
```

try this link http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/